# What is wrong with the following coffeescript code

Tags: javascript, syntax, coffeescript

I'm very new to coffee-script. I kept getting the error:

```
error: unmatched OUTDENT
        product = new Model2({
```

Here is the code:

```
describe 'Test case 1', ->
    describe 'Method 1', ->
        it 'should compile this code into javascript', (done) ->
            Model1 = mongoose.model 'Model1', schema.Model1
            Model2 = mongoose.model 'Model2', schema.Model2
            product = new Model2({
                test: 'This is a test'
            })
```

Can you help me identify where the errors could be in that code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check if you mixed tabs and spaces? (that line and the line above it)

Comment: Best way to solve it is to remove all the indentation near that error and create it again, using `tab`

Comment: Thanks, it's the problem with the tabs.